# Link not passing values to target page

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I'm currently trying to make a cards page region in oracle apex where each card has a link that passes a column value to a target page.  The values in the link builder are correct and when I look at the debugger it seems to be assigning the values correctly as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R5ur.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Deleting and recreating the page solved the issue, I think it had something to do with the fact that it was created as a form page in the page creation wizard